# window.onscroll css transformY transition flickering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms

In my react project I want the navigation to hide when scrolling down and show when scrolling up. I am using window event listener for scroll which fires my `toggleNavigation` function and CSS `transform: translateY` and `transition`. The navigation flickers when scrolling up or down no matter if I use mouse wheel, keyboard arrows or drag scrollbar.
(There are some other conditions when to run `toogleNavigation` but they are not relevant.)

**Navigation component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default Navigation = () => {
  const [prevScrollpos, setPrevScrollpos] = useState(window.pageYOffset);
  const [translateY, setTranslateY] = useState("0");

  const toggleNavigation = (prevScrollpos) => {
    const currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (currentScrollpos > prevScrollpos + 50) {
      //navigationHtml.style.top = '-116px'
      setTranslateY("-116px");
      setPrevScrollpos(currentScrollpos);
    } else if (currentScrollpos + 50 < prevScrollpos) {
      //navigationHtml.style.top = '0'
      setTranslateY("0");
      setPrevScrollpos(currentScrollpos);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      toggleNavigation.bind(this, prevScrollpos)
    );
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleNavigation);
    };
  }, [prevScrollpos]);
  return (
    <nav style={{ transform: `translateY(${translateY})` }}>
      <ul>
        <li>random text 1</li>
        <li>random text 2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  background-color: orangered;
  position: fixed;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

**Working codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-haze-flfjj?file=/src/Navigation.js

**So far I've tried and did not work:**

In react: changing the limit when to hide/show nav from 50 to 100 or 1

In CSS:

- changing `translateY` to `translate3D`
- using `translate3D(0,0,0)` on other elements
- setting `backface-visibility: hidden` on nav and other elements

Before I used changing `top` instead of `translateY` but the animation wasn't fluent and snappy, though it was without flickering.
I tested it in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Opera and the issue is present in all of them.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It worked fine in my laptop :D

Comment: It works fine on my desktop/Win10/Chrome.

Comment: I found out it works fine for a moment after I refresh the page. However, the more I scroll the worse it gets.

Comment: This is a problem of mine currently, I use vue, but I don't really use anything special besides pure JS to solve this

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem on my own. The issue was my bad designing in React. I shouldn't have used `useState` hook to track scrolling as it causes rerendering the component by design. The laggy behaviour was evident after a couple of scrolls. It took more scrolls on more performant PC (more component rerenders) to be laggy.
Now I track scrolling with a simple `let` variable and the navigation component rerenders only when it shows or hides.

**Codesandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-minsky-00xi0?file=/src/Navigation.js

Answer (score 0):

Nice to hear that it works fine.
But you could go further as computing thing on a scroll event is never really a good idea as it is triggered so many times. If you have other scroll events on your web page, it could become slow / laggy.

**You could also add throttling to scroll event, using a custom Hook**

**Here is an example of a throttled scroll event Hook (SRR compatible):**

```
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
    // You can use Lodash throttle function or aby other one, your own, whatever...
    import { throttle } from "lodash"
    
    function useDocumentScrollThrottled(callback) {
      const [, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)
      let previousScrollTop = 0
    
      function handleDocumentScroll() {
        const { scrollTop: currentScrollTop } =
          typeof window === "undefined" || !window.document
            ? 0
            : document.documentElement || document.body
    
        setScrollPosition(previousPosition => {
          previousScrollTop = previousPosition
          return currentScrollTop
        })
    
        callback({ previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop })
      }
    
      // => 250: 4fps / triggered times per seconds (250 is in milliseconds) || 16: 60fps (because 1000/60 = ~16) 
      const handleDocumentScrollThrottled = throttle(handleDocumentScroll, 250) 
    
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleDocumentScrollThrottled)
    
        return () =>
          window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleDocumentScrollThrottled)
      }, [handleDocumentScrollThrottled])
    }
    
    export default useDocumentScrollThrottled
```

**Then in your component** (your Nav component by example) **you can use it that way:**

```
export default function Nav() {
      const MINIMUM_SCROLL = 30;
      const TIMEOUT_DELAY = 50;
      const [shouldHideNav, setShouldHideNav] = useState(false)  ;
    
      useDocumentScrollThrottled(({ previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop }) => {
        // Do whatever you want like by example
        const isScrolledDown = previousScrollTop < currentScrollTop;
        const isMinimumScrolled = currentScrollTop > MINIMUM_SCROLL;
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShouldHideNav(isScrolledDown && isMinimumScrolled)
        }, TIMEOUT_DELAY)
      })

      return (<nav className={`nav ${shouldHideNav ? 'nav--hidden' : ''}`}>Nav content</nav>)
}
```